# Rtweet get_timeline no longer showing user_id or screen_name

Tags: r, twitter, timeline, tweets, rtweet

I am looking to pull a set of Tweets for multiple users, the rtweet package. When I have used the get_timeline() function previously, the output has included the user_id and screen_name of the account. This is particularly important when pulling Tweets for multiple users so that you can identify who the Tweet belongs to.

However, in a recent update, this function no longer pulls any identifying user information. We now get id and id_str which are unique to the Tweet but don't tell us whose timeline we are pulling from. Any idea how to reattach a screen_name to the output or a way to identify the output?

```
accounts <- c("BarackObama", "justinbieber")
timelines <- get_timeline(accounts, n = 100, token = auth, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

| id | id_str |
| --- | --- |
| 1.436416e | 1436416270426050566 |
| 1.437194e | 1437194052122906626 |

Comment: This was answered in the thread in rOpenSci discuss, see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73372112/2886003